# Travelling Salesman Problem solver?

Tags: open-source, maps, optimization, openstreetmap, travel

I am looking for an open-source Travelling Salesman Problem solver that can do at least what [Optimap](https://gebweb.net/optimap/) was able to do:

- bulk import a list of ≥500 addresses/coordinates (one per line)
- compute the minimal distance route
- display a map of the optimized tour

Comment: Offline, online, operating system?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Either/both. Linux.

Comment: By address, you mean human readable address, not Lat/Lon?

Comment: Certainly interesting: http://map.vroom-project.org/ (which can import Lat/Lon), so you'd just need a service which converts the address into their coordinates.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks. "_you'd just need a service which converts the address into their coordinates._" I have a Python script that uses the Google Maps API to do that.

Comment: Okay, then there's a solution to your problem. How much usability / GUI do you need? How many TSP problems do you need to solve per day/month?

Comment: @ThomasWeller "_How much usability / GUI do you need?_" GUI would be nice, but CLI-only is , too. "_How many TSP problems do you need to solve per day/month?_" About 1 per day.

Comment: @ThomasWeller "_map.vroom-project.org_" It throws an error on my CSV (~500 lat./lon. pairs): "Warning : only the first 101 locations where used. Unfound locations(s):" (list of lat./lon.s), and only a dozen or so points appear on the map, and no route was computed.

Comment: Wow, 500 locations. Maybe you want to [edit] the question and include that as a requirement now that we know what the problems might be.

Answer (score 1):

[OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/) (java) and [OptaPy](https://www.optapy.org) (Python) both support TSP (as well as more advanced variants). See the TSP example in optaplanner-examples and the youtube video that demonstrates it.

For openstreetmap data, you'd integrate with GraphHopper or OSRM. See the optaweb-vehicle-routing GitHub repository on how to do that.

Comment: Wow, OptaPy even does scheduling optimization.